# Alfresco: change document content without changing the version

Tags: java, rest, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I've an Alfresco Community 6.2 version and I need to update the content of some documents without incrementing the version, from an external process.
I've the following behaviour now:

The nodes to be modified have aspect cm:versionable and I cannot change that; If I update the content using REST API trough this PUT `https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/aaa/content?majorVersion=false` a new minor version is being created.

I cannot remove the aspect because otherwise also the other previous versions of that node (manually created) will be removed, and I cannot afford that.

Is there a way? or some workaround using internal java API or CMIS something??

Thanks

Comment: Write it in Java, and disable the Version related policies before you do the write?

Comment: with`disableBehaviour(actionedUponNodeRef, ContentModel.ASPECT_VERSIONABLE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply update a node's content by using

```
PUT ​/nodes​/{nodeId}​/content
```

You can disable a node's autoversioning behavior by setting `"cm:autoVersion"=false`

Alfresco's version behavior is a bit different as you may expect:

- The main node is stored in `workspace://SpacesStore`
- A version is implemented as a read only snapshot copy in `workspace://version2Store` by either checkout/checkin or by behavior
- You can only update the main node's content and Alfresco is faking the main node as latest version (you can check that using the node browser)
- when you remove the aspect you only modify the versioning behavior but you will not remove the snapshotted versions in `workspace://version2Store`
- Versioning behavior is controlled by either alfresco-global.properties (e.g.`version.store.enableAutoVersionOnUpdateProps=true`) and/or by the aspect `cm:versionable` attached to a node
- Alfresco Share, CMIS & REST will automatically add the versionable aspect on node creation having the following defaults (which can be modified in alfresco-global.properties):

  - `cm:initialVersion=true`: indicates that when the versionable aspect is applied, an initial snapshot of the node is taken at that point
  - `cm:autoVersion=true`: indicates that when ever a change is made to the content of a node, a new snapshot version will be created in the version store
  - `cm:autoVersionOnUpdateProps=false`: indicates that when ever a change is made to the *properties* of a node, a new snapshot version will be created

Comment: With `"cm:autoVersion"=false` do you change the behaviour of the entire Alfresco installation or of a single node?

Comment: it's a property to be set on a node. Check global parameters from [repository.properties](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-community-repo/blob/c319370d4e97b8813d441b7d37d622982be6334c/repository/src/main/resources/alfresco/repository.properties#L374) to be overwritten in alfresco-global.properties

Comment: I don't understand, if it is to be overwritten in alfresco-global.properties how can it be set on a single node?

Comment: the factory defaults are defined in repository.properties and can be overwritten in alfresco-global.properties. These values are used to set the initial properties when adding the aspect. For existing nodes you have to modify the properties.

Comment: I had a try: if I put cm:autoVersion=false on a document, and later I add a new version with a rest API call, it's version is still incremented. Why?

Comment: you add new version or you update content via `PUT ​/nodes​/{nodeId}​/content`?

Comment: that is what I've done, but still a minor version was created. The node had still the cm:versionable aspect and the cm:autoVersion was on false. I did the test on Alfresco CE 6.2